# Issue comparing Registry Key Value Names using string methods

Tags: c#, string, registry, string-comparison

Ok guys, I'm having a really strange issue where I'm looking at Regedit right now and I can see the reg key that I'm looking for exists.

This is the code I'm using to detect it

```
public static void GetSoeRegKey()
{
    RegistryKey soeKey = Registry.CurentUser.OpenSubKey("TechTools", true);

    if (soeKey != null)
    {
        foreach (string value in soeKey.GetValueNames())
        {
            //Here's where the problem lies
            if (value.Equals("SOEEncPass"))
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I've stepped through the code, and every time it is finding the reg key and the `soeKey.GetValueNames()` method is returning the values correctly.

However, even though I can clearly see that the value that I'm searching for is being returned the `if (value.Equals("SOEEncPass"))` never evaluates to true.

I've tried it as `value == "SOEEncPass"` and `string.Compare(value, "SOEEncPass")` with all of the `StringComparision` options but no matter what I do the line `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);` is never executed.

Am I missing something with the string comparison, or is there a quirk to reg keys that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so here it goes:
Your code worked for me (meaning the comparison returned true) with both Equals and '==', though I used my own keys of course. Here's my code, and a picture of the key I looked for.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey soeKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Console");

            if (soeKey != null)
            {
                foreach (string value in soeKey.GetValueNames())
                {
                    //Here's where the problem lies
                    if (value.Equals("FontWeight"))
                        Console.WriteLine(value);
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

[image: I looked for FontWeight and it worked]

Hope this helps somewhat... the problem is not in the comparison part. Are you sure you are comparing to the right name / value?

EDIT: I tried it with both REG_SZ and REG_DWORD types and both worked. Strange indeed

Comment: Thanks Tamás, yes I can see the one of the values being returned by `GetValueNames` as `"SOEEncePass"`. For Info the value is created as REG_SZ type, although I doubt that makes any difference.

Comment: Only thing I did differently was I did not open the subkey for writing. But I assume you need to do that (plus it would be silly if the was the root problem).

Comment: Could it be because of the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Can you export the key and it's values into an .reg file and post it here for analysis?
Perhaps there are extra characters (i.e white space) in the value name.
You can also try a case-insensitive comparison:

```
string.Compare(value, "SOEEncPass", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Sorry Udo, the value in question holds an encrypted password, so I can't share it.